# If an item selected in jComBox1 then it should be disabled in all other combo boxes

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Hello I'm still newbie on java hope to learn this nice feature...
Hello i have 4 combo box that have the same inside and inside of it is

```
-Select-
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
```

and when I choose `Item 1` on `comboBox1`,
 the `comboBox2,comboBox3 and comboBox4` have elements only these

```
-Select-
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
```

and then when I choose `Item 3` on `comboBox2`, the `comboBox3 and comboBox4` have this leftover elements

```
-Select-
Item 2
Item 4
```

anyone have idea how to do this on Java? I am using GUI Builder on Netbeans...

**EDIT 1**

this is my Code

```
private void jComboBox1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
    jComboBox2.removeItem(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
    jComboBox3.removeItem(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
    jComboBox4.removeItem(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
}
```

and I add on the same code `jComboBox2, jComboBox3 and jComboBox4` after that...
when I go choose `-Select-` the `-Select-` is gone too... and

one more problem is when I already choose all and thinking to rechange it again... all items are gone and no more choices anymore.. I just want to back the available items again...

**EDIT 2**

**Example**

```
jComboBox1
-Select-
Item 1
Item 2 <-- I select Item2, then the other combo box will remove Item 2**
Item 3
Item 4

jComboBox2
-Select-
Item 1
Item 3 <-- then I select Item 3
Item 4

jComboBox3
-Select-
Item 1
Item 4 <-- then Item 4

jComboBox4
-Select-
Item 1
```

but i'm changing my mind... then I need to go back to  `jComboBox2` to select `Item3`
so I choose
`jComboBox2` and select `-Select-`, so I can select `item3` on `jComboBox4`

but the result is
jComboBox4
null (no items)

Comment: Seems like a single `JList` that allows selecting multiple items would be easier and less confusing to the end user.  This 'nice feature' reads like 'unusable GUI in the making' to me.

Answer (score 0):

When the state of some combobox changes, you should not only remove items from other comboboxes, but also insert.
For example, if **item1** was selected, and then you decide to select **item3**, you have to to remove **item3** from all other comboboxes and insert **item1**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some kind "proxy" model to filter the individual comboboxes...

Instead of trying to add and remove items from different combo boxes, you could start with a single master combo box model, which contains all the available items.

Each combo box would then have their own "proxy" model (using the master model as a base), which would then have the ability to "filter" items from the list that is used by the combo box.

In that way, you would simply need to tell the "proxy" model's which items to filter out and allow the underlying API to take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the "Select" problem you can verify if selected index is different of 0 (assuming that "Select" option is always the first).

Every time you you change a combo, you need remove the selected item on others combos and add the unselected items on others combos.

Answer (score 0):

You could create all of those boxes and options using loops much more cleanly. This code is untested, but it should work.

```
//Declare and initialize the options that the comboboxes will have
String[] options = {"-Select-", "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"};
//Declare and initialize an array that will hold the currently selected options in each combobox by index
//For example the currently selected value of comboBoxes[1] is selected[1]
String[] selected = {"-Select-", "-Select-", "-Select-", "-Select-"};

//Declare and initialize an array of comboBoxes. 
//Four comboboxes will be created all containing the options array
JComboBox[] comboBoxes = new JComboBox[4];
for(int i = 0; i < comboBox.length; i++) {
    comboBoxes[i] = new JComboBox(options);
}

private void jComboBox1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
    //Loop through all of the comboboxes in comboBoxes
    for(int i = 0; i < comboBoxes.length; i++) {
        //Check to see if the current combobox in the array matches the source of your event
        if(evt.getSource() == comboBoxes[i]) {
            //Get the string value of the combobox that fired the event
            String currentSelection = (String)comboBoxes[i].getSelectedItem();
            //Make sure that the value actually changed
            if(!currentSelection.equals(selected[i]) {
                //If the previous value of the combobox was "-Select-" don't add it to all the other comboboxes
                if(!selected[i].equals(options[0])) {
                    //Add back the previous value to all comboboxes other than the one that fired the event
                    for(int j = 0; j < comboBoxes.length; j++) {
                        if(j != i) {
                            comboBoxes[j].addItem(selected[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                //If current value of the combobox is "-Select-" don't remove it from all other comboboxes
                if(!currentSelection.equals(options[0]) {
                    //Remove the current value from all comboboxes other than the one that fired the event
                    for(int j = 0; j < comboBoxes.length; j++) {
                        if(j != i) {
                            comboBoxes[j].removeItem(comboBoxes[i].getSelectedItem());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Set the selected item for the combobox that fired the event to the current value
            selected[i] = currentSelection;
        }
    }
}
```